# How to build a collaborative app using Google Drive as storage?

Tags: google-drive-api, collaboration, data-synchronization, google-drive-shared-drive

I am writing an app with JSON as the file format to store the data. I want the users to store those JSON files in their own Google drive so that they can share the files to their friends as they want. And their friends can also open my app at the same time to collaborative real time.

Google Drive API allows an app to create and delete files in users' Google drive. But how can my app support collaboration like Google Docs or Google Sheets, so that 2 or more people can work on the same file and the change will be saved back to the Google drive and updated on the other side in the real time?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to create a [Permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions) for each user/group you wish to give access to the file.*

#### Example:

Using the [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) API method, you can create a permission and attach it to the file.

The following example shows how to give a user write permissions using the Google API JavaScript client:

```js
// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function execute() {
  return gapi.client.drive.permissions.create({
    "fileId": "-some-do",
    "resource": {
      "role": "writer",
      "type": "user",
      "emailAddress": "someuser@domain.com"
    }
  })
}
```

#### References:

- [Permissions | Google Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions)
- [Permissions: create | Google Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Comment: Thanks @rafa-guillermo. I see the Permission is required before people can collaborate on the same file. Let say I created the Permission for 2 users. How can the users see the live update from other users, like what happens in Google Doc?

Comment: If someone is editing the document then the edits show up immediately for other people viewing the document, if that's what you mean?

Comment: This is correct @rafa-guillermo. It's the same behavior as Google Doc. Do you know if it's possible for this real-time collaboration based on Drive API?

Comment: @CupidChan You will probably need to use the Drive Activity API (https://developers.google.com/drive/activity), where you can subscribe to changes of files and folders.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo If I want to collaborate on a file in Shared Drive, is it sufficient to set the permission to the domain or do I need to set the permission for every individual user?